# Image is not displayed sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I am displaying images in my page so i am using Image control

```
<m:Image src="{path: 'MyModel>Link', formatter:'.formatter.imageFormatter' }" visible= "true" alt="{i18n>picname}"></m:Image>
```

and the formatter

```
imageFormatter: function(val) {
        return val;
    },
```

when i see the network in the debbuger the image is loaded perfectlly with status 200 and when i see preview it is an empty image But in My page nothing is displayed (When i open the image in other tab when i go back to my app all images are displayed )
I Don't know the problem

Comment: Is this in Fiori Launchpad?

Comment: @Marc no standalone app

Comment: Hi Simon - in order to help you will need to provide: the data model binding in the controller (since you get a 200 in the chrome debug tool this is likey an issue) and possible a bit more of the XML View.

Comment: <m:Table items="{MyModel>/Images}" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true">
 <m:headerToolbar>
  <m:OverflowToolbar></m:OverflowToolbar>
 </m:headerToolbar>
 <m:columns>
  <m:Column></m:Column>
 </m:columns>
 <m:ColumnListItem>
  <m:cells>
   <m:VBox>
    <m:VBox>
     <m:Image src="{path: 'MyModel>Link', formatter:'.formatter.imageFormatter' }" visible="true" alt="{i18n>picname}"></m:Image>
    </m:VBox>
   </m:VBox>
  </m:cells>
 </m:ColumnListItem>
</m:Table>

Comment: @Bernard am sure the binding is correct other properties are working only the images are not ( am getting the data from an odata)

Comment: does {i18n>picname} bind properly to your resource model? i.e. is there a pictureless entry with a tooltip with the corresponding text?

Answer (score 0):

Set the "densityAware" property to false in the sap.m.Image control and try again

Comment: Could you set a console.log(val) in your formatter, before the return statement and see in the console it the printed path is correct? Including the file name and the extension?

Comment: yes i did that and it returns the correct path i paste it in other tab and it shows the image

Comment: do you it's an issue with the control ?

Comment: Ok, I saw in your comments that you have a VBox-VBox-Image. VBox are flexible, so they can give you problems with heights and widths if you don't manage them correctly. Images could be one of those scenarios, because the VBox is added to the DOM before the image is downloaded, so it is rendered without knowing the image width... So it gets width zero. Delete the VBoxes inside your cells and leave only the Image and see what happens.

Comment: @RafaelLópezMartínez i did as bernard suggested above (without Vbox but the same issue ) :(

Answer (score 0):

Simon.
Set a value in the Column Header - e.g.: (please namespace correctly - you need to prefix with m:)

```
<Column 
    hAlign="Center"
    visible="true"
    width="145px">
    <Text text="Image"/>
</Column>
```

Not doing so may be having consequences you are not anticipating.
Also, to me, your cells collection seems incorrect - can you try:

```
<m:items>
    <m:ColumnListItem type="Navigation" detailPress="onEdit">
        <m:cells>
            <m:Image src="{path: 'MyModel>Link', formatter:'.formatter.imageFormatter' }" visible="true" alt="{i18n>picname} />
       </m:cells> 
    </m:ColumnListItem>
</m:items>
```

Comment: i tried that but the same behaviour the image is not displayed but once i open it in other tab it is displayed correctly

Comment: I am not following you - i do not know what you mean by the above

Comment: sorry i mean it is the same issue it is not solved when i tried your solution

Comment: I find that curious because the XML View syntax you posted was, as best I understand, incorrect. So I am not sure how you had it working at all? If the code you are trying works but doesn't show the image - that is one thing - however if the code as a whole doesn't work - we could be on a wild goose chase. Do you get a table with rows but no image or do you get no rows?!

Comment: i get a table with rows but no images ( i tried that in explorer too and it doesn't show the image )